# Option to Create a Custom Action of Action Type Send Email not visible on Custom Object

Tags: email, publisher-action, quickaction, custom-actions

I intend to Create a `Send Email` - `Custom Action` on a `Custom Object`, but `New Action` screen does not show `Email` as an available `Action Type`.

Is there something that need to be configured for Creating a Custom Email Publisher Action for a custom object?

I've verified, Activities is enabled on the Custom Object, and I'm working in a Developer Organization (if there is a certain setting specific to Developer orgs).

***Note:*** *In the Organization I can see the `Send Email` as a `Global Action`. And Also I can see the Send Email Action available in Custom Object Page Layout as well, but when I go in to Create a new custom action, I don't see 'Send Email' as available Action Type.*

**Here is how the `Create Action` screen looks like in my org:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your org doesn't have `email-to-case` enabled. If you enable `email-to-case` automatically `Send Email` action will be available.

[image: Email-to-case]

Send Email is available across all objects

[image: Send Email Action]

Comment: I enabled it, but I don't see the "Send Email" action in Action Type list. Though I would like add more info here that, "Send Email" is available as Global Action without "Email-to-case" enabled, just not available on Custom Object as Action Type when creating new Action.

Answer (score 0):

It is available by default for all objects, screenshot is below - 
[image]